# Can a sentence start with 'as' ? Is it okay?

Tags: sentence-starts

Is it okay to use 'As' at the beginning of the sentence?

Example: `As there are lots of tourist facilities along the Mediterranean Region, as there are getting more every year.`

Comment: The first "as" is correct, the second isn't. I think the sentence you're looking for "As many tourist facilities as there are along the Mediterranean region, there are getting to be more every year." Or "... there are more and more every year."

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4FXSnoy71Q4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, it's a myth that you can't use a [coordinating conjunction](http://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/wrtps-srch?lang=eng&srchtxt=coordinating%20conjunction&i=&lettr=indx_catlog_s&cur=1&nmbr=&comencsrch.x=0&comencsrch.y=0) at the start of a sentence. (Of course, it may not be somebody's policy or style to do so——but it's not ungrammatical. There is no rule that is being broken.) Among the sources for this, see articles by [Oxford Dictionaries](https://blog.oxforddictionaries.com/2012/01/05/can-i-start-a-sentence-with-a-conjunction/) and [Quick and Dirty Tips](https://www.quickanddirtytips.com/education/grammar/can-i-start-a-sentence-with-a-conjunction).

Second, *as* is not actually a coordinating conjunction—it's a [subordinating conjunction](http://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2guides/guides/wrtps/index-eng.html?lang=eng&lettr=indx_catlog_s&page=96V0BrGwoO_g.html). As far as I know, nobody has ever claimed that you cannot (as preference or rule) start a sentence with a subordinating conjunction. (There is only a problem if the sentence that starts with a subordinating conjunction has a single clause.)

Adding to what has been said by others, here are some possible ways to rephrase your sentence so it is grammatically correct—with *as* at the start (and two clauses):

> As there are lots of tourist facilities along the Mediterranean region, the number of tourists increases each year. [This is grammatically correct, even if it doesn't logically follow.]
>
> As the number of tourists to the Mediterranean region increases each year, so does the number of tourist facilities.

Of course, I may be misinterpreting what you had meant to say in the first place. If you had actually meant to say that there are a lot of tourist facilities and that the number of these facilities increases each year, then I can think of no rephrasing in which starting the sentence with *as* makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be using "*as*," to substitute for the conjunction, "*because*," at least in the first instance. In that case, it is generally OK to start a sentence with "as," particularly in informal writing. Some purists would argue that one should never start a sentence with a conjunction in formal writing, but the tide is beginning to turn on that former truism. Still, my advice is to be aware of your audience and, if uncertain, consider revising the sentence to avoid starting with a conjunction. [Personally, I'm fine with it.]

However, if your example was intended as a single sentence with both "*as*"s (so to speak) to be included, the sentence simply does not seem to make sense, as suggested by Green Grasso Holm.